# SQL Cursor conversion of date

Tags: sql, cursor

I have a table which stores the birthdate in column pnr as YYYYMMDD-XXXX. I'm trying to do a conversion of this to date in order to calculate their age (at the moment just trying to print it out even). But getting stuck on the conversion of the date, haven't used cursors before so unsure where to place this.

I've tried placing it already in the cursor but then getting issue with casing the type.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE bilägare(
pnr VARCHAR2(13) PRIMARY KEY,
 VARCHAR2(20),
enamn VARCHAR2(20),
bor_i VARCHAR2(20),
jobbar_i VARCHAR2(20));
```

```
   CURSOR c_bil IS
       SELECT fnamn, enamn, pnr
         FROM bilägare;
v_fnamn bilägare.fnamn%TYPE;
v_enamn bilägare.enamn%TYPE;
v_pnr bilägare.pnr%TYPE;

BEGIN
if not c_bil%isopen then
open c_bil;
end if;

   LOOP
   fetch c_bil
   into v_fnamn, v_enamn, v_pnr;
   exit when c_bil%notfound;

      Dbms_output.put_line(Initcap(v_fnamn) || ': ' ||Initcap(v_enamn) || ': ' ||to_date(substr(1,v_pnr,8),'YYYYMMDD'));

   END LOOP;
   close c_bil;
END;
```

Comment: Please tag appropriate database name and some sample data from your table.

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.